# How to join two pyspark dataframes in python on a condition while changing column value on match?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes like this:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 11, 1999, 1999, None), (2, 22, 2000, 2000, 44), (3, 33, 2001, 2001,None)], ['id', 't', 'year','new_date','rev_t'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(2, 44, 2022, 2022,None), (2, 55, 2001, 2001, 88)], ['id', 't', 'year','new_date','rev_t'])
df1.show()
df2.show()

+---+---+----+--------+-----+
| id|  t|year|new_date|rev_t|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|  1| 11|1999|    1999| null|
|  2| 22|2000|    2000|   44|
|  3| 33|2001|    2001| null|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+

+---+---+----+--------+-----+
| id|  t|year|new_date|rev_t|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|  2| 44|2022|    2022| null|
|  2| 55|2001|    2001|   88|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
```

I want to join them in a way that if `df2.t == df1.rev_t`  then update `new_date` to `df2.year` in the result dataframe.
So it should look like this:

```
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
| id|  t|year|new_date|rev_t|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|  1| 11|1999|    1999| null|
|  2| 22|2000|    2022|   44|
|  2| 44|2022|    2022| null|
|  2| 55|2001|    2001|   88|
|  3| 33|2001|    2001| null|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a column from `df2` in `df1`, you use left join + `coalesce` function for the column you want to update, in this case `new_date`.

From your expected output, it appears you want also to add the rows from `df2`, so union the join result with `df2`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = (df1.join(df2.selectExpr("t as rev_t", "new_date as df2_new_date"), ["rev_t"], "left")
          .withColumn("new_date", F.coalesce("df2_new_date", "new_date"))
          .select(*df1.columns).union(df2)
          )

result.show()
#+---+---+----+--------+-----+
#| id|  t|year|new_date|rev_t|
#+---+---+----+--------+-----+
#|  1| 11|1999|    1999| null|
#|  3| 33|2001|    2001| null|
#|  2| 22|2000|    2022|   44|
#|  2| 44|2022|    2022| null|
#|  2| 55|2001|    2001|   88|
#+---+---+----+--------+-----+
```